# Запись в файл json, содержащего Unicode-символы

Tags: python, json, unicode

Как правильно сериализовать (и записать в файл) словарь, содержащий `unicode` символы, чтобы он был `человекочитаемым`?

Предположим, есть следующий код `(python3)`:

```
import json
person = {'name': 'Дима'}
person_json = open('person.json', 'w')
json.dump(person, person_json)
person_json.close()
```

Результатом его исполнения является файл со следующим содержимым:
`{"name": "\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430"}`

И вопрос, собственно говоря, в том, как записать `json` в файл, чтобы получить следующее содержимое: `{"name": "Дима"}`.

Интересно так же решение для `python2`, если оно будет отлично для `python3`.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import json

person = {'name': 'Дима'}

person_json = open('person.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

json.dump(person, person_json, ensure_ascii=False)

person_json.close()
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как последовательность `\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430` гарантирует `ascii` символы? Просто непонятно значение флага `ensure_ascii`. Ведь `\u0414` -  это код поинт в 2 байта, который никак не может быть обработан `ascii`, где максимум 1 байт. Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать про флаг, и почему он именно так называется?

Comment: Если `ensure_ascii` имеет значение `true (по умолчанию)`, на выходе гарантированно будут экранированы все входящие символы не ASCII. Если `ensure_ascii` имеет значение `false`, эти символы будут выводиться как есть.  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html?highlight=dump#basic-usage

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
person_json = open('person.json', 'w')
json.dump(person, person_json)
```

напишите

```
person_json = open('person.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
json.dump(person, person_json, ensure_ascii=False)
```

чтобы русские буквы были записаны в кодировке UTF-8, но не в виде ASCII последовательностей их Юникоде численных кодов.

Comment: Вы наверное смотрели мой ответ выше?

Comment: @S.Nick - Да, я даже голосовал за него.

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от моего?

Comment: @S.Nick - другим подходом - выбором самой важной части, объяснением, соблюдением [PEP 8](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id28).

Comment: `\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430` - это же не `ascii` последовательность. Или любая байтовая запись является валидной с точки зрения `ascii`? Возьмём, к примеру, первый символ – `\u0414`.  `0414` -  это 16-тиричное число, которое в десятичной системе ранвно `1044=(4*(16**2) + 1*(16**1) + 4*(16**0)`. Но в `ascii` максимум 1 байт и максимальное число `255`. Где в моей логике ошибка или тогда что именно означает флаг `ensure_ascii `? Спасибо!

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий - Система Юникод присваивает каждому знаку целое число в диапазоне от `0` до `0xFFFFFFFF` - т.е. даже **4 вайты**. Но для большинства языков (включая русский) достаточно **2 байтов** - это так называемый *Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).* Каждое число из BMP возможно кодидровать в виде **6 ASCII символов** - первые 2  - `\u` - обозначают, что это Юникод кодировка одного символа (Unicode escape sequence), так что последующие 4 будут его шестнадцатеричным представлением в Юникоде (Code Point).

Answer (score 1):

Более удобный вариант с менеджером контекста (гарантирует, что файл будет закрыт):

```
person = {"name": "Дима"}
filename = "test.json"

with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(person, file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Содержимое файла:

```
{"name": "Дима"}
```

В теории, должно и для Python 2 работать, судя по примеру из [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).